# converting List type with Lambda Java

Tags: java, lambda

If I have an expression:

```
  / List<Long> /                   / List<String> /
s.getPhones().addAll(Arrays.asList(rs.getString("phones").split(",")));
```

Can I use Java Lambda to convert types with Long.parseLong in pritty form without "for loop" ?
Or even if will use for loop, it will became more "codeless".

How it must look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `List<String>` to a `Stream`, map the elements to `Long`, then collect them back to a `List<Double>` that is suitable to pass to `addAll` on `s.getPhones()`.  No lambda expression is necessary because of the method reference, but streams makes this easier.

```
s.getPhones().addAll(
    Arrays.asList("123,456,789".split(","))
        .stream()
        .map(Long::valueOf)  // You could use: (s -> Long.valueOf(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```